# how to store 2 billion users?

Tags: database-design

There is a portal with two billion users registered. If you store all the 2 billion users in a conventional databases it will take more time to retrieve the data about a particular user when that user tries to login. How do you handle this situation to make sure that the user gets the response quickly.

Comment: so 1 in every 3 people in the world is registered on this portal?.... do tell!     Question too vague.

Comment: Clear out the database...no seriously, don't get me wrong, but if you have an online community with 2 billion users, you should really think about a spring-cleaning...or you've just beaten Facebook by 1.6 billion users...

Comment: "There is a portal with two billion users registered."  That's a pretty bold claim.

Comment: 2 billions? This seems really too much :) You mean that one third of the whole planet does have an account on that portal? Zuckerberg shall tremble!

Comment: Have you measured and thus proved that conventional database approach is *too* slow? You know, they are pretty good at searching records. It's their primary function after all. Besides, http://www.internetworldstats.com/stats.htm claims there's 1.8 bln internet users in the world, so you'd have quite a penetration with 2 bln accounts, as others mentioned :)

Comment: It's easier to store them if you cremate them first!  (They take up SO much less space that way!)

Comment: `for(long i = 0; i< 2bil; i++) { CreateUser(); }`

Comment: What database software?  Have you tested how long it takes to retrieve a record given an indexed key?  Seriously, when I went to a Oracle User Group meeting, I was astonished by what the DBAs meant when they talked about medium and large databases.

Comment: @David - Out of curiosity, what did they mean when they talked about medium and large databases?

Comment: You guys are taking this a little too seriously. I think he just wants to know how to handle a database with a large number of records.

Comment: @Svish:  I don't remember the details, but certainly a large database would be in the billions of rows at least.  Databases do handle transaction data, and the number of transactions for a large company can easily get into the billions.  Bear in mind that two billion records at 400 bytes per record will easily fit on one single disk nowadays, so that's not large at all.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see any particular reason why a conventional database on decent modern hardware couldn't retrieve log-on information pretty quickly, even if you have 2 billion records. It's just a simple indexed lookup after all (you did remember to index on user ID, right?)

On a really big machine you might even fit most of it in RAM.

However, if you are really trying to engineer this for scale I'd look at something like [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/). This is a highly available, distributed NoSQL database, basically the same kind of architecture that Google, Facebook etc. would use.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its practical, but in theory you could use some sort of tree structure.  If I remember my CS classes from a long time ago, trees are O(ln), so for a billion (which is 2^30), you only ever need 30 operations for a lookup.  Thats the beauty of CS....

Implementing a tree structure for that, i have no idea.

Comment: There is a family of tree structures optimized for storing large amounts of data (i.e. too large to fit into main memory). They're called B-Trees. And now guess how pretty much all databases implement their indexes...

Comment: #Michael Borgwardt -- right.  I didnt know if this a practical "I need to do this" question or a theoretical question.  Sounds like homework or an interview question to me...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a portal of 2 billion users, login is such a small amount of all the queries that will be performed.
The problem here is not the time it takes for 1 login, but what if one percent of all users is active at the same time.
Luckely two billion users do not fit into one continent, so you can use distributed database servers, that each serve their own part of the world. And you can synchronize them in the background (in case somebody travels to another continent).

If you have the resources (time, money, staff) you can invent your own bigtable database like google did (with 2 billion user you probably have money and staff), but I would stick with the normal relational databases to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

As of the mentioned scenario, say if feasible...
Even making usage of any kind of advanced data structure won't help.
because, practically when you are creating a tree (say for the mentioned scenario..)
it indirectly induces at least 2 linkage pointers for each and every node...
that is kind'a hypocritical phenomenon to maintain for the order of billions.

One of the kind, we can rationalize the users,
simply decentralize the users according to some sorting scenario
(say based on the order of alphabets in their usernames)...
as of we can say the username will be the inducing power behind the user's instance
running behind..
if so, we will be maintaining separate database for every alphabet
and these data bases will be communicating through some centralized commanding tree
so that if request fires will automatically receives the resolution from the server..

next of the kind,
maintain location of the user as an external parameter so that,
the users of one region may be mapped along a sub network which was in return
connected to a centralized commanding gateway..
(kind'a similar scenario to that of The Internet...)

In my point of view, this is a bit practical
as of to mention the procedures of META, managing its user's info in a nutshell..
to get clarity try to observe the facebook's working architecture on managing nodes
in its network.....