# How can a large website (like a dating site) store comparisons between all it's users?

Tags: database-design, bigdata

So, the math that has got me thinking is, 5million users - we want to be able to rank by similarity, and various other tasks that probably make calculation on the spot not practical..

```
5,000,000 ** 2 = 25,000,000,000,000
```

Even if we were to assume that each comparison record is `1 Byte`, that is `25 PBytes`!Not to mention a massive amount of processing when data for a user is altered.

Is this just the cost of doing such a task? What tech (soft and hard) could be used to store a `trillion records`? (and they probably want to be significantly bigger than 1 byte each!)
Or are there other better solutions to this kind of problem?

Comment: First of all, I don't think there is much point practically in calculating and storing metrics for each and every unique pair of users. I think in practice the matching scope is reduced significantly by taking things like location, sex, age and likely more into account. Indexing database by those fields enables reasonable search time. Keeping a cache of a dozen or so of reasonable matches that seemed to interest a particular user (E.g. those user clicked on) as a short list might be reasonable.

Comment: Yes - I guess avoiding storing a comparison for every user to each other is a good start - but down to "a dozen or so" matches  is going way too far! I guess I am not only after ways to avoid such a big set of data, but still end up dealing with a very large set of data - and ways to deal with it!

Comment: In such case check out distributed databases and sharding (MongoDB might be a good start).

Comment: This is a very broad question; I don't think SO is the place for it.  That said ... high-level answer follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We generally handle the front end with a variety of algorithmic filtering techniques: train on a small subset at the start, using a tailored, scalar similarity metric to cluster the data or cast it into a sparse graph.  This clustering allows us to make basic inference about possible matches, derived from the existing ones.  Interest thresholds also play a part.

For instance, consider that A and B are in the same cluster, with a match of 0.94.  Y and Z have the same in another cluster.  Then we do some inter-cluster checks -- and find that A and Z match at 0.10.  If our interest threshold is 0.80 (and we can likely tune this for each cluster), then we know that there's no way B and Y can meet that threshold.  In most cases, we can eliminate entire clusters for B without further computations: depending on the distance metric that derives from our similarity metric, we can set a strict cutoff for B against anyone already measured against A.

Also, when we're looking for "best N matches", we can raise that bar with a few checks within B's native cluster.  A new user gets similar treatment: identified with one cluster, perhaps a couple others noted, and the rest is derivative with high thresholds.

Changing user data doesn't require more work than ingesting a new user, and often is easier, as not that much data changes.  The user's original record quite likely serves as the proper touch-point.

Your back-end concerns have a partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259730/how-to-store-2-billion-users?rq=1).  There are a lot of large-DB tools to handle big data, research you [should have done](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question on it.

Also, there are several big-data [machine-learning engines](http://blogs.gartner.com/alexander-linden/2015/11/30/4-four-new-open-source-machine-learning-frameworks-from-ibm-msft-google-and-intel/) appearing on the scene, in addition to some of the more established ones (research, again).

Disclaimer: I work on Intel's Trusted Analytics Platform.  The opinions and suggestions herein are my own.